# How to count document elements inside a mongo collection with php?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have the following structure of a mongo document:

```
{
 "_id": ObjectId("4fba2558a0787e53320027eb"),
 "replies": {
    "0": {
      "email": ObjectId("4fb89a181b3129fe2d000000"),
      "sentDate": "2012-05-21T11: 22: 01.418Z" 
    } 
    "1": {
     "email": ObjectId("4fb89a181b3129fe2d000000"),
     "sentDate": "2012-05-21T11: 22: 01.418Z" 
    } 
    "2" ....
 }

}
```

How do I count all the replies from all the documents in the collection?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

In the following answer, I'm working with a simple data set with five replies across the collection:

```
> db.foo.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fba6b0c7c32e336fc6fd7d2"), "replies" : [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fba6b157c32e336fc6fd7d3"), "replies" : [ 1, 2 ] }
```

Since we're not simply counting documents, [db.collection.count()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Count) won't help us here. We'll need to resort to [MapReduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce) to scan each document and aggregate the reply array lengths. Consider the following:

```
db.foo.mapReduce(
    function() { emit('totalReplies', { count: this.replies.length }); },
    function(key, values) {
        var result = { count: 0 };
        values.forEach(function(value) {
            result.count += value.count;
        });
        return result;
    },
    { out: { inline: 1 }}
);
```

The map function (first argument) runs across the entire collection and emits the number of replies in each document under a constant key. Mongo will then consider all emitted values and run the reduce function (second argument) a number of times to consolidate (literally reduce) the result. Hopefully the code here is straightforward. If you're new to map/reduce, one caveat is that the reduce method must be capable of processing its own output. This is explained in detail in the MapReduce docs linked above.

Note: if your collection is quite large, you may have to use another output mode (e.g. collection output); however, `inline` works well for small data sets.

Lastly, if you're using MongoDB 2.1+, we can take advantage of the [Aggregation Framework](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation+Framework) to avoid writing JS functions and make this even easier:

```
db.foo.aggregate(
    { $project: { replies: 1 }},
    { $unwind: "$replies" },
    { $group: {
        _id: "result",
        totalReplies: { $sum: 1 }
    }}
);
```

Three things are happening here. First, we tell Mongo that we're interested in the `replies` field. Secondly, we want to unwind the array so that we can iterate over all elements across the fields in our projection. Lastly, we'll tally up results under a "result" bucket (any constant will do), adding `1` to the `totalReplies` result for each iteration. Executing this query will yield the following result:

```
{
    "result" : [{
        "_id" : "result",
        "totalReplies" : 5
    }],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Although I wrote the above answers with respect to the Mongo client, you should have no trouble translating them to PHP. You'll need to use [MongoDB::command()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.command.php) to run either MapReduce or aggregation queries, as the PHP driver currently has no helper methods for either. There's currently a MapReduce example in the PHP docs, and you can reference [this Google group post](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mongodb-user/Ct7grUaxT7Q/discussion) for executing an aggregation query through the same method.

Comment: Hi there , just want to know how could this be applied for counting all the replies from one single document in the collection

Comment: You could use an aggregation pipeline similar to my example, starting with [`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/match/) to narrow things down to a single document; however, I think the easiest method would be to simply select the document and count the array length in your application. If you're concerned about the data size, you can project a single field from the array of embedded documents (e.g. `{replies.author}`), or even a missing field to get an array of empty objects back (still countable).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked your code, might work as well. I've did the following and it just works:

```
$replies = $db->command(
   array(
       "distinct" => "foo",
       "key" => "replies"
        ) 
   );
$all = count($replies['values']);
```

Comment: So long as each reply element is a unique value, `distinct()` should  yield the expected answer. I imagine that may be less efficient (especially for larger values and data sets), as distinction is more complex than summating array lengths.

Comment: I'll try your solution, you're right about performance... Do you have any idea how to check performance for mongo from php?

Comment: Check my gist linked in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10655998/162228) for a simple timing example. For actual MongoDB query profiling, you may want to look at: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler

Answer (score 0):

I've did it again using the group command of the PHP Mongo Driver. It's similar to a MapReduce command.

```
$keys = array("replies.type" => 1); //keys for group by
$initial = array("count" => 0); //initial value of the counter
$reduce = "function (obj, prev) { prev.count += obj.replies.length; }";
$condition = array('replies' => array('$exists' => true), 'replies.type' => 'follow');
$g = $db->foo->group($keys, $initial, $reduce, $condition);
echo $g['count'];
```

Thanks jmikola for giving links to Mongo.

Answer (score 0):

JSON should be

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("4fba2558a0787e53320027eb"),
  "replies":[
             {
             0: {
                     "email": ObjectId("4fb89a181b3129fe2d000000"),
                     "sentDate": "2012-05-21T11: 22: 01.418Z" 
                 }, 
             1: {
                     "email": ObjectId("4fb89a181b3129fe2d000000"),
                     "sentDate": "2012-05-21T11: 22: 01.418Z" 
                }, 
             2: {....}
           ]

}
```